# Sanitize (radio buttons, checkboxes and <option>)

Tags: php, sanitization

In PHP, does one have to sanitize these types of inputs: `radio` buttons, `checkbox`es and `<option>`? Or do only the inputs where the user can enter arbitrary text have to be sanitized?

Comment: Sanitize everything, be paranoid!! :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The form you send to the client does not, in any way, limit what data they can send back.

So, yes, you need to provide sanity checking and suitable escaping for every piece of incoming data.

Answer (score 2):

Do you use `PDO`?

If not you need to sanitize them. Especially for `<option>any value'here</option>`

Comment: i am using mysqli and prepared statments. So this preocupation doesn't make sense. Correct?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answers, doing a custom ('hacked') POST/GET is always (easily) possible. You should always check EVERY variable that is customizable