# How to concatente $_POST value from radio buttons into PHP string?

Tags: php, sql

I need to take the value given from my radio buttons and add to the string of my where clause to the update the where clause that will run as part of my query. I am unsure on how to concatenate the $_POST['answer'] onto $where in the second if block

The current code:

```
<form action="assignment.php" method="POST">
<input type="submit" name="start" value="start game">

<?php
$query = "SELECT `message`, `parentID`,`answerYesID`, `answerNoID`, `nodeID` FROM     `creature`";
$where = "";

if (isset($_POST['start'])){
  $where = "WHERE `nodeID` ='1'";
}


if (isset($_POST['submit']) && (isset ($_POST['answer']))){
        $where = "WHERE `nodeID` =";
}

$result = mysqli_query($dbconn, $query.$where);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) ;
echo $row['message'];
?>

<input type="radio" name="answer" value="<?php echo $row['answerYesID'];?>">yes
<input type="radio" name="answer" value="<?php echo $row['answerNoID'];?>">no
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you provide your database dump? Also better to use PDO or MySqli instead of mysql_

Comment: @alexeypalamar Already he's using `mysqli_`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$where = "WHERE `nodeID` = " . $_POST['answer'];
```

or if you need it in quotes:

```
$where = "WHERE `nodeID` = '{$_POST['answer']}'";
```

Comment: $where = "WHERE `nodeID` = '{$_POST['answer']}'" worked perfectly, thankyou very much

Comment: Great! Just a note, it seems that it is good practice to sanitize the input - something I left out. But anyways glad it worked for ya! eh ... checkmark? :)

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it right, might be you missed a space between `creature` and `where`, try:

```
if (isset($_POST['start']) && isset ($_POST['answer'])){
                                 #always a good idea to clean user input
   $where = " WHERE `nodeID` = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($dbconn,$_POST['answer'])."'";
            #^ left a space here
}

#You do not need the second isset().

$result = mysqli_query($dbconn, $query.$where);
```

Comment: Is it necessary to sanitize radio input?

Comment: @MarkM, Yep, I do mostly.. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6280951/1003917)

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran Lol I was just reading that same post. Thanks, good to know!

Answer (score 0):

First of all what you are doing is a very bad idea! you can assign value to your radio buttons and you can just change the id in you query depending upon the radio value.

For your answer, use this

```
$result = mysqli_query($dbconn, $query.' '.$where);
```

I think you need a space between `$query` and `$where`

Comment: thanks but it works now. The concatenation between $query and $where was always working anyway

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="assignment.php" method="POST">
<input type="submit" name="start" value="start game">

<?php
$query = 'SELECT `message`, `parentID`,`answerYesID`, `answerNoID`, `nodeID` 
FROM     `creature`';
$where = ' ';

if (isset($_POST['start'])){
  $node = 1;
  $where .= 'WHERE `nodeID` = ?';
} elseif (isset($_POST['submit']) && (isset ($_POST['answer']))){
  $node = $_POST['answer'];
  $where .= 'WHERE `nodeID` = ?';
}
if ($stmt = $dbconn->prepare($query.$where)) {
  $stmt->bind_param('i', $name);
  $stmt->execute();
  while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    echo $row['message'];
  }
}    
?>

<input type="radio" name="answer" value="<?php echo $row['answerYesID'];?>">yes
<input type="radio" name="answer" value="<?php echo $row['answerNoID'];?>">no
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
</body>

</html>
```